# Want to submit a form on enter even if no form element has focus

Tags: javascript, html, swing, angularjs

I'm working on a angular app that is replacing a current thick client that was made in swing.  One of the behaviors differing between html that swing is the notion that you can set a button as the default actor on an enter key press from anywhere on the page.

In html or course you need to either have that in focus or it has to be a submit button on a form and a form element must be in focus.

I'm using angular so its pretty easy to start to add this feature. Currently what I'm thinking is to listen on document for keydowns, if the source of the event is an element that doesn't have a enter use case then I'll submit the form.  But I feel un easy about this.  Anyone have any experience tying to do this.

Comment: this feels like a really bad idea.

Comment: @pennstatephil that is the same feeling I get.  If I've learned anything its not to fight a form.

Comment: I would push back on this. This is not the "normal" behavior for forms.

Answer (score 0):

What you do basically is sending a `$broadcast` from an element, and then add a directive to the submit button which would listen for it: `$scope.$on`.

Comment: That would only provide a way to alert the submit that something is calling it.  It wouldn't provide a way to pick up enter key presses that haven't been acted upon yet.